# sending and recieving ROS messages to non-ROS machine

Tags: c++, udp, ros

Newbie to ROS and networking. Need some help here to understand the best approach i should take. I am trying to send Ros messages from a ROS PC to another non-ROS PC.  There is a few way I researched that I can do it.

1. Install ROS on the non ROS machine. Connect it like a network. One will act as master with a common roscore for all
2. Write a ros node and recieve the ROS messages and then serialize them as UDP/TCP messages and broadcast them over the network
3. Through rosbridge and websockets writing json

Method 1 is probably not possible as there is a requirement is that we will have to reuse the WCF interface in the non-ROS PC.

Method 2: I wanted to get some help and insights about the tools/ packages/ libraries in ROS that can help with this. Have anyone has any template or could point me to a guide/website for some help?

Also I am puzzled to of why TCP is promoted over UDP or at least I have the impression.

Method 3: This seems a bit easier (on first look) but I have out that communicating through websockets is not so much supported(not sure if i use the right words) by WCF. Am I right?

Thanks for answering my query

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at ipc_bridge. Just a suggestion
https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~meam620/wiki/index.php?n=Roslab.IpcBridge

Comment: thanks. I will take a look at the link'

Answer (score 0):

What ROS topic does is wrap a series of data types (ROS messages) into a buffer and transport it through the network using either TCP or UDP protocol.

Every node publish its data on a 5-digit port on ROS network. I think you can listen to that port using plain socket-programming method and deserialize (I never checked, but I think deserialize methods are determined in [genmsg](http://wiki.ros.org/genmsg) package) based on the ROS message and I think you can get data out of the ROS system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **rosserial** would to the job. *rosserial* is a protocol for wrapping standard ROS serialized messages and **multiplexing multiple topics and services over a character device** such as a serial port or network socket.

Video: https://youtu.be/JEwhXWKXlI0

Wiki.ros : http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial